# How to reinitialize - access videojs.players not possible in minified version

Tags: video.js

Using the developer version of video.js 4.0 I'm able to reinitialize a video by simply emptying the players variable before the reinitialization: `videojs.players = {};`.
However, this is not possible using the minified video.js variant, as the variable's name is minified too. This leads me to the assumption, that what I'm trying to achieve is supposed to be done another way.
How do you solve this issue?

UPDATE

Since version 4.1, the variable videojs.players ist exported. However, the reinitialization does not succeed using the original minified js file. Can anyone confirm that?